# Complete output of a list of METAR data not possible with my solution approach

Tags: python, formatting

Got a list like this `data = ['KSFO 072156Z 28020KT 10SM CLR 18/06 A3006 RMK AO2 PK WND 28027/2149 SLP177 T01780061']`

and would like to output it to the command line as follows :

```
KSFO            072156Z         28020KT
10SM            CLR             18/06
A3006           RMK             AO2
PK              WND             28027/2149
T01780061
```

i tried this

```
x = 0
l = []
for i in data:
    x = x + 1
    l.append(i)
    if x == 3:

        print(f"{l[0]}\t\t{l[1]}\t\t{l[2]}")

        l = []
        x = 0
```

but the problem is that this solution omits results. in the case of the example, "T01780061" is not output with my solution approach.

if the length of the list "data" cannot be divided by 3 my solution does not work anymore or it can be executed but does not output everything as shown in the example above

i know probably the solution to this is very simple but i have been trying for weeks and can't come up with a reasonable solution

thank you in advance

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is to print each word individually, and just change the `end` parameter to `print` dependent on whether you are at the end of the line or not. For example:

```py
data = ['KSFO 072156Z 28020KT 10SM CLR 18/06 A3006 RMK AO2 PK WND 28027/2149 SLP177 T01780061']

for s in data:
    words = s.split()
    for i, w in enumerate(words):
        print(w, end='\n' if i % 3 == 2 else '\t')
```

Alternatively you could iterate over the `range` of the `words` and print a `join`ed string of the current 3 values:

```py
for s in data:
    words = s.split()
    for i in range(0, len(words), 3):
        print('\t'.join(words[i:i+3]))
```

In both cases the output is:

```
KSFO    072156Z 28020KT
10SM    CLR     18/06
A3006   RMK     AO2
PK      WND     28027/2149
SLP177  T01780061
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to achieve what you need:

```
from more_itertools import chunked

data = ['KSFO 072156Z 28020KT 10SM CLR 18/06 A3006 RMK AO2 PK WND 28027/2149 SLP177 T01780061']
for line in chunked(data[0].split(), 3):
    print('\t'.join(line))

KSFO    072156Z 28020KT
10SM    CLR 18/06
A3006   RMK AO2
PK  WND 28027/2149
SLP177  T01780061
```

(`more_itertools` is available via `pip install more-itertools`)